# How to control the speed of UIView animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I am implementing a rotating digit view like this:
https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTNumberScrollAnimatedView

But, instead of scrolling from say 1 to 9, I want the animation to continue scrolling (1 to 9 then back to 1 to 9), until I manually stop it.

I implement this by adding UILabel subviews 1-9, vertically stacked, and add an extra label for number 1 at the bottom. When rotating to the bottom (showing the bottom label 1), in the animation completion closure, I set the transform back to origin, showing top label 1, and restart rotating animation.

This works fine, but since each rotation (1-9-1) is separate, the animation from 1-9 accelerates and then stop at 1, and pick up speed at the next iteration. This is not what I want, I want the rotation to maintain a constant speed between the iterations.

How can I do this with UIView animation?

Here is the code:

```
 public func startAnimation(){
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeIn)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(self.loopDuration), animations: { [unowned self] in
        self.container!.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CGFloat(-(self.endNumber-self.startNumber+1)*(self.size)))
    }) { [unowned self] (completed) in
        if self.isAnimationStopped {
            self.container!.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeOut)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(self.loopDuration), animations: {
                self.container!.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CGFloat(-self.targetY))
            })
        } else {
            self.container!.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            self.startAnimation()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default UIView animation uses `ease-in, ease-out` animation timing, where the animation accelerates smoothly, runs, then decelerates to a stop.

You need to use a longer form of UIView.animate, `animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`  that takes an options parameter, and specify a timing curve of `.curveLinear`.

Just specify 0.0 for the delay and `options: .curveLinear`

### Edit:

Note that if you need to specify multiple options, like `.curveLinear` and `.allowUserInteraction` you would use `OptionSet` syntax, like `options: [.curveLinear, .allowUserInteraction]`

Comment: Like a charm. Thanks!